error in POM.XML file while executing Spring file
I am executing first spring boot program  with eclipse i tried with Spring Initializer,inbuilt spring framework but when project is created it immediately shows error in POM.XML file for Parent tag and project tag.enter image description here
I have tried

By updating Maven.
By deleting .m2 file and updating ]
and so on. please Help

